# Error with PowerShell Extension dependency Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure

Tags: powershell-extensions

I've installed Sitecore Powershell Extensions version 5.0 on Sitecore 8.2 update 7, I also installed Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure as it was a dependency. I installed this library through NuGet and then added a reference to it in my Visual Studio project. After publishing to my local site I get this error when trying to access Sitecore:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure'
>   or one of its dependencies. **Strong name signature could not be
>   verified.  The assembly may have been tampered with, or it was delay
>   signed but not fully signed with the correct private key**.

I'm not sure where the problem is. Anyone have any ideas?

I'm on a Win7 platform running IIS.

Comment: Have you tried installing Windows Management Framework 5.1 on the Windows 7 machine?

Comment: I wasn't aware that was a requirement. It should be mentioned in the GitBook and the Marketplace. I'll do that install and see if that fixes it.

Comment: The book does in fact document here https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/installation that the Windows Management Framework 3+ is required. I recommend you use the latest version supported for Windows 7 since it comes with many improvements for PowerShell.

Comment: @MichaelWest thanks, I must've missed it somehow. I stand corrected. This worked by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using Windows 7 my best guess is the issue relates to the fact that your OS does not have Windows Management Framework 3 or newer.

You can read more about that requirement here: https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/installation

Simply install WMF 3 (preferably 5.1) and then everything should work as expected.